# Al subir pagina web no cargan nuevos cambios

Tags: html

Buen día!, estoy trabajando en un sitio web que regularmente se hace una modificación cada mes, en esta ocasión llego un cambio de emergencia en un banner, pero al sobreescribir la imagen no muestra la nueva.

He visto que esto se debe a que está cargando la página almacenada en la caché porque si abro en modo incógnito si muestra los cambios, al igual que si la cargo pulsando ctrl + f5 actualiza correcto.

El problema es que el público que visita la página sigue viendo la anterior, y no tienen conocimiento que es por este motivo. mi pregunta es si **hay una manera de forzar desde el servidor o desde el código HTML/PHP que los navegadores vuelvan a cargar la caché** o de que manera se podría solucionar este tema.

**He leído que el navegador vacía la cache cada determinado tiempo en automático, pero ¿Qué tanto tiempo debe de pasar para que esto suceda?**, he realizado pruebas y mi navegador ya van 2 días que no hace cambios cargando una web de prueba.

**Nota: La nueva imagen subida como banner tiene el mismo nombre que la anterior, solo se sobreescribio.**

Comment: Pueden ser muchas cosas... estás usando un cdn para el dominio? como cloudflare? si es así, tenés que borrar el cache desde su panel. Una opción mejor es agregar una query a la URL de la imagen. Por ejemplo: `image.png?1` podes ir incrementando el número cada vez que hagas un cambio, asi sigue funcionando el cache y no hay conflicto con los navegadores del cliente ya que fuerza a recargar la nueva imagen.

Comment: si estas en linux haz ctrl+r si es windows shift+F5

Comment: @CristianF. Tienes razón Cristian, aun que actualizar el banner por la facilidad de solo sobrescribir quita el trabajo de entrar al portal a cambiar detalles o agregar la query al código es lo mejor para evitar que ocurra esto a futuro, muchas gracias me ayudo mucho!

Comment: @DavidGonzalo Gracias David!, no sabia que usando shift + f5 recargabas la pagina con el cache, me evitara a futuro estar abriendo el modo incognito cada que haga un cambio para ver el resultado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la forma mas sencilla es versionar los archivos como comenta Cristian F.

de igual forma puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
<img  src="<?php $versión= rand(12,99999); echo "img/tuimg.png?n=".$versión; ?>" alt="imagen" >
```

Esto obliga al navegador a ver que es una nueva versión de tu archivo y leer todo el archivo de nuevo

Comment: Excelente!, fue la respuesta complementando con la de Cristian F. agregando eso a la pagina parece hacer siempre la actualizacion, lo ideal seria versionar e ir incrementando siempre de 1 para yo igual ir teniendo un control de versiones, muchas gracias!